# SCEditor - make the default font Arial

Tags: fonts, sceditor

How can [SCEditor](https://www.sceditor.com/) be forced to start with Arial as its default font when it is empty? The default appears to be a Serif font - perhaps Times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style of WYSIWYG content is the browsers default style.

It can be changed by setting the [`style` option](https://www.sceditor.com/documentation/options/#style-a-id-style-a) in the constructor. It's recommended to use (or base your style on) the `content/default.min.css` style as it contains some other important CSS.
Something like:

```js
sceditor.create(textarea, {
    // other options here
    // ...

    // Set the style for the content of the editor
    style: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sceditor@3/minified/themes/content/default.min.css'
});
```

or it can be set via the [css() method](https://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/css/#css), e.g.:

```js
instance.css('body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }');
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the answer, but hope this helps anyone looking to set the Editor's default font.

Create the editor like this:

```
var obj = $('<selector>');
sceditor.create(obj, {
  // Options go here
});
```

Then do

```
var instance = $(obj)[0]._sceditor;
instance.css('body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }');
```

Thanks.